# CListView sorting on data from another table

Tags: yii, date-sorting

I have a table that stores information about a role. In that table I have two fields that store the ids from other tables.

Table one: id, rname, pname, idtwo, idthree

Table two: id, twoname

Table three: id, threename

My ClistView displays rname, pname, twoname, threename

With this forums help I was able to use a CListView and display the names from tables two and three.

What I would now like to do is be able to do is create a view where the information is sorted on twoname and aonther view where the data is sorted on threename.

My actionIndex is:

```
public function actionIndex() {
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Staffroleprofile');
$this->render('index', array(
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
));
}
```

and my _view.php is:

```
<h1>List of SRP's</h1>
<?php 
$dataProvider->sort->defaultOrder='rname ASC'; 
?>

<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
'itemView'=>'_view',
)); ?>
```

so the above gives me the data sorted by rname from table one. How would I specify that I want the data to be sorted by the data in table two or three?

Kind regards,

e25taki

Comment: Do you have models for tables 2 and 3?

Comment: Yes I do topher. I have created models via Gii for all tables. Cheers e25taki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `model2` and `model3` are the relations for table 2 and 3 respectively in `Staffroleprofile`, add this to your code

```
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Staffroleprofile');
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->together=true;
$criteria->with=array('model2','model3');
$dataProvider->criteria=$criteria;
$dataProvider->sort->defaultOrder='model2.twoname ASC';
```

`CDbCriteria::together` specifies whether the query should be run using a join. If set to false additional queries are run for each record if a relation is required. For more detail go to the API pages for [CDbCriteria](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria) and [CActiveDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveDataProvider)

Comment: Hello topher, in model1 I have the relations                 'sitename'=> array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Acdsite', 'idsite'),                           
                        'businessname'=> array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Business', 'idbusiness'),                                                         in my actionIndex_bysite I added the code:

Answer (score 0):

all good now, the code I required was:

```
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Staffroleprofile');
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->together=true;
$criteria->with=array('sitename','businessname');
$dataProvider->criteria=$criteria;
$dataProvider->sort->defaultOrder='sitename.site ASC';
$this->render('index_bysite', array(
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
));
```

so, you get ba handle to the records from the Staffrleprofile model and then add the criteria for the sorting, in this case it was based on a relation.
Thank you all for your assistance. Another little step in my Yii learning adventure.

Cheers!

e25taki